# OTB plugin not working

Tags: qgis

I tried to follow this tutorial above and its not working for me.
I'm getting an error code message : An error has occurred while executing Python code:

**Error code message :**

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\PROGRA~2/LOGICI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ConfigDialog.py", line 517, in select
> self.lineEdit.setText(text)
> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted

```
Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.22.7-Białowieża Białowieża, 5a65627a 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~2/LOGICI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/helle/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/helle/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~2/LOGICI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\lib
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\GDAL-3.4.3-py3.9-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~2\LOGICI~1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/helle/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/helle/OneDrive - AGC2I/MASTER/Stage/LETG
```

**Tutorial :**

> The QGIS-OTB plugin (requires QGIS > 3.2)
> With QGIS < 3.8 you will need to manually install the plugin. You can follow the instruction here: https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin#otb-provider-for-qgis-processing
>
> With QGIS > 3.8, the plugin is already in the QGIS core. So you just need to install OTB and activate the plugin: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/QGISInterface.html#open-processing-settings
>
> Download and Install OTB
> OTB is not distributed with qgis-otb-plugin. It is a separate project and has its own git repository. Download > latest OTB version: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/download/.
>
> Configure plugin in QGIS
> Restart QGIS, then install the OTB plugin: > Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins.
>
> Click on Installed tab on left and make sure box next to OrfeoToolBox (OTB) is checked.
>
> Open processing settings
> Settings -> Options -> Processing (left panel)
>
> You can see OTB under “Providers”:
>
> Expand OTB tab
> Tick Activate option
> Set OTB folder. This is location of your OTB installation.
> Set OTB application folder. This is location of your OTB applications. <OTB_FOLDER>/lib/otb/applications
> Click “ok” to save settings and close dialog. If settings are correct, you will have OTB algorithms loaded in Processing toolbox